# char * to array<unsigned char^>

Tags: c++-cli

I have a program that sends data through serial port. I store my data to be sent in a native `char` array (it has to be in that way, simply can't use managed buffer), but when it is time to sent to buffer via call to `Write(cli::array<unsigned char^>, ...)` method, it does not accept the pointer to the native array as a first argument as expected. I can simply copy contents of naive `char` buffer to managed `array<unsigned char^>` buffer then pass this buffer to the function `Write(...)` as a first argument but this is surely time consuming. Is there a way to cast `char*` (or `unsigned char*`) to `array<unsigned char^)` so that I can avoid copying the memory content?

Comment: Do you have a `std::array` of managed pointers, or do you have a managed pointer to a `std::array`? It's not quite clear from reading the question title and text. Please show some code instead, like your declarations, and at least the prototype of the function you try to call.

Comment: I'd like to know why you can't use a managed buffer. You could simply pin it in memory and get a native pointer to the contents.

Comment: I have a buffer which is declared as char buffer[SIZE] as already mention as a native char array and sen this buffer via serial port by calling Ports::Write method.

Comment: @napyonsen see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27311565/1207195): simply you cannot cast unamanged memory to an unmanaged type (it doesn't matter they are/they may be _compatible_). Workaround is to allocate buffer in managed side and take a native pointer to expose it in unmanaged world.

Comment: I cant use managed buffer because I simply send some structs in a source file written for embedding purpose. What I am doing here is a kind of simulation(or verification)

Comment: If you can't change native source code (moving **allocation**, nothing else, outside it) then you have to copy data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't *cast* an unamanged native `char*` array to `array<unsigned char>^`. For that you have to copy data from one to the other. If you really cannot drop unmanaged buffer (I doubt but I don't see code and I don't know your reasons) what you can do is to create a managed array, pin it and use it in your unamanged functions:

```
#pragma unmanaged

void work_with_native_buffer(char* pBuffer, size_t size) {
    // Do your unmanaged stuff here
}

#pragma managed

ref class Test {
public:
    void DoNativeStuff() {
        if (_buffer == nullptr)
            _buffer = gcnew array<unsigned char>(256);

        pin_ptr<int> pinnedBuffer = &_buffer[0];
        char* pBuffer = pinnedBuffer;
        work_with_native_buffer(pBuffer, _buffer->Length);
    }

    void SendData(Stream^ stream) {
        Debug.Assert(_buffer != nullptr);

        stream->Write(_buffer, 0, _buffer->Length);
    }

private:
    array<unsigned char>^ _buffer;
};
```

In short you have a managed buffer but you pin it, it won't be relocated by GC and you have a native pointer for its access by native functions. Your unmanaged code will not change but you revert where allocation is.

If native code is in another DLL you may also use marshaling but IMO it will hurt performance (in my experience overhead in serial ports/sockets is pretty high).

Comment: This didnt solve my problem because I still use managed buffer _buffer for storing. Thank you though.

Comment: Yes, **that** is the point! You have a managed buffer you can use with managed classes but also you have an _unamanged_ (!!!) pointer to access that buffer from _unamanaged_ code. The other way (allocate in _unmanaged_ and use in managed is simply **not possible** unless you implicitly or explicitly make a copy). If you worry about performance...stop to do it, there isn't any difference (well _in theory_ to allocate managed memory is even faster). About marshaling: please note that _out_ arguments (in case you're supposing to allocate in unmanaged world) are marshaled.

Comment: You are right, this solutions sounds not but as I already tried.